# Unable to change style of UITableView to Grouped in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, uitableview

It'a s simple app, window based.

The window has a UINavigation Controller, and the Controller has a UITableView built from
New File-UIViewController subclass- UITableViewController option check.

I set the style for the UITableView to Grouped in the Interface Builder, but the table stayed Plain in the Simulator.

I wonder if I missed any options?

XCode 3.2.6

iOS SDK 4.3

Any help is appreci

Project download: [Zip File@Google Docs 692k](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxLbGdIIFl7KZGI2ZjMzMWEtYWVhOS00ZGIyLWIxNTgtMWFmMWJlMmE0Zjhi&hl=en)

Comment: I know I always forget to save the xib in IB...

Comment: Is your IBOutlet linked correctly to the tableView?

Comment: I thinks the link is good. Plain view displays well. The problem is now solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController so it's creating a tableView for you and ignoring yours. Change the superclass of tViewController to UIViewController and it will use the tableView you have defined in IB.

Comment: Worked out pretty well! Thanks for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've properly specified the nib file (remember: iOS is case sensitive) for the controller and connected the table in the nib to File's Owner. Otherwise, the controller will create its own table, which is probably what's happening.